# Able to access variable inside one if-statement but not other

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

Here's a snippet from my code and it's weird why I'm able to access the variable named 'calBegPoint ' inside 3rd if statement but not the second.

```
if graph != None:
                for trace in graph['data']:
                        if 'LSR(' in trace['name']:
                                calBegPoint = trace['x'][0]      #Statement 1
                        if '% change' in trace['name']:
                                print(calBegPoint)       #Statement 2
                        if 'LSR Extended' in trace['name']:
                                print(calBegPoint)        #Statement 3
```

When I run this code, I get the following error on Statement 2 but, if I comment it, I do not get the error for Statement 3. To solve, this problem, I tried declaring `calBegPoint= "Hi"` before the entire snippet. With that I did not get the error but, the value printed on Statement 2 was 'Hi' and not the one I calculated.

I've been trying to debug it for hours. Any direction/pointer will be appreciated

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'calBegPoint' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Try to reason out what happens when for the first element of `graph['data']` the first `if` statement does not trigger, but the second or third.

Comment: @timgeb: You're a genius!!! Thanks a lot for the help! You can put that in the answer, I'll accept it. That's all I needed. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message tries to tell you that you use `calBegPoint` before defining it.

In your case, the first execution of the second or third `if` statement lies before the first execution of the first `if` statement.